# Preload / Pre-populate PouchDB in React Native Application

Tags: react-native, pouchdb

Is it possible to preload / pre-populate a database in my React Native application and then the first time it is run, simply do a sync?  I already have most, if not all of the database information before the app is distributed, it would be awesome if it just had to do a quick sync when the app is run.  Any ideas how I would go about doing that?

I found this - https://pouchdb.com/2016/04/28/prebuilt-databases-with-pouchdb.html but it doesn't mention React Native

Using:

- pouchdb-find: ^7.0.0
- pouchdb-react-native: ^6.4.1
- react: 16.3.1
- react-moment: ^0.7.9
- react-native: ~0.55.2

Thanks for any pointers.

*Update* Here is the code I'm using to try the loading of a dump file.  This code exists in /screens/Home.js
The dump file is located in /client/dbfile/database.txt

```
var db = new PouchDB("cs1");

db.get("_local/initial_load_complete")
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log("loading dumpfile");
    if (err.status !== 404) {
      // 404 means not found
      throw err;
    }
    db.load("/client/dbfile/database.txt").then(function() {
      return db.put({ _id: "_local/initial_load_complete" });
    });
  })
  .then(function() {
    // at this point, we are sure that
    // initial replication is complete
    console.log("loading is complete!");
    return db.allDocs({ include_docs: true });
  })
  .then(
    function(res) {
      // display all docs for debugging purposes (empty)
      console.log(res);
    });

this.localDB = db;
```

When this runs my console displays this - showing there have been 0 rows added.

```
Object {
    "offset": 0,
    "rows": Array [],
    "total_rows": 0,
}
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Object {
    "message": undefined,
    "name": "unknown",
    "status": 0,
}
```

Comment: Follow up: I attempted loading from a dump file in the article above, however I'm getting `db.load is not a function. (In 'db.load("client/dbfile/database.txt")', 'db.load' is undefined)` error message

Comment: Could you share the code?

Comment: Follow up: Resolved the load is undefined issue, I had to install this https://github.com/pouchdb-community/pouchdb-load  and add the plugin `PouchDB.plugin(require('pouchdb-load'));`  However, I'm not getting back any docs.  Updating my initial question with some code

Answer (score 0):

I found that the `db.load()` function from the [pouchdb-load](https://github.com/pouchdb-community/pouchdb-load) module requires a URL. I was pointing it to a file path on the device's filesystem. I placed my database.txt file on my server, changed it to use the url and it worked.

In my mind this isn't ideal because if they install the app and have slow wireless, it still has to pull the file from the server.  It is still much faster than performing a full-on replicate when the app opens for the first time however.

Comment: Infinitely faster... so it takes literally 0 time now? :)

Comment: But on a more serious note... I don't think this answer is complete. What is `db.load()`? That's not part of the regular (documented) PouchDB API. Are you using a plugin? It would be good to include that here.

Comment: Yes, the initial load time is almost immediate, its fantastic.  I used this module - https://github.com/pouchdb-community/pouchdb-load

Answer (score 0):

In my project I have couple of db docs I distribute with app (translations JSON is the one good example).
So at app init I just try to read translations doc from db, if there is none - I import content from js module and store in db.
Then translations changes just being replicated from server to local db.

```
//transmob.js
const transMobFile = {
//content goes here
);
module.exports = transMobFile

//dbInit.js
import transMobFile from 'data/transMob';
..
PDB.getDoc('TransMob')
.then((doc)=> {
  if (!doc) {
  global.locales = transMobFile.localesMob; // locales
  global.translations = transMobFile.langMob; // translations
  return PDB.saveDoc('TransMob', transMobFile)
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use react-native-fs to load a file from /android/app/src/main/assets. Just put the file into the assets folder and read it with RNFS.readFileAssets.

```
import PouchDB from 'pouchdb-core';

PouchDB
 .plugin(require('pouchdb-find'))
 .plugin(require('pouchdb-load'));

import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';

const localDB = new PouchDB("cs1", {adapter: 'asyncstorage'});


localDB.get("_local/initial_load_complete")
 .catch(function(err) {
   console.log("loading dumpfile");
   if (err.status !== 404) {
    // 404 means not found
     throw err;
   }

 RNFS.readFileAssets('yourdb.txt', 'utf8')
    .then((contents) => {
      localDB.load(contents).then(function() {
        return localDB.put({ _id: "_local/initial_load_complete" });
      }).then(function() {
        // at this point, we are sure that
        // initial replication is complete
        console.log("loading is complete!");
        return localDB.allDocs({ include_docs: true }).then(
          function(res) {
            // display all docs for debugging purposes (empty)
            console.log(res);
          });
      }, function(err) {
        console.log(err);
      });
    })
 })
```

You'll need to rebuild your project, reloading is not sufficient.
My project crashes when I attempt to load a 30MB file, so I probably will split it into a few smaller files. Check out https://github.com/pouchdb-community/pouchdb-load to see how this works if needed.

Comment: hmmm, installed it, linked it, added the import, modified my code, getting Error: readFileAssets is not available on this platform